# Formula for a geometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-series

Helping my brother with his math homework and I am hung up on this one.

Find a formula for $a_n$ for the geometric sequence:
$a_1=2$, $a_{k+1}=-3a_k$

If anyone here can help that would be great. Thanks. My thought would be that I just need to turn the formula above into $a_k = ____ a_{k-1}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a_n=2\cdot (-3)^{n-1}$, or $\,(-1)^{n-1}\, 2\cdot 3^{n-1}$ , if the sequence indices begin at $n=1$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
a_n = (-1)^{n+1} (2)( 3^{n-1})
$$

Comment: May I suggest $ (-1)^{n+1}$ is the same as $ (-1)^{n-1}$?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks you !

Answer (score -1):

I think you are searching for $a_n = 2\cdot(-3)^n$